# Docker service causes 100% CPU usage

Tags: linux, arch-linux, linux-kernel, docker, manjaro

Recently, my CPU has been adopting a very strange behavior. I noticed a strong slowdown when running my typical setup, which includes around 20 docker services. It feels like my laptop became unable to keep up with the load for seemingly no particular reason on my side, rendering it practically unusable for work even though it's around 2 months old.

I spent an extensive amount of time troubleshooting and researching a solution already. My kernel is `4.19.60-1-MANJARO`, and I tried virtually everything that's listed into the [CPU frequency scaling](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_frequency_scaling) article of ArchWiki.

```
$ grep "model name" /proc/cpuinfo
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8265U CPU @ 1.60GHz
```

I changed the governor to `performance` on all eight cores using `cpupower` and even tried setting up the minimum allowed frequency to 2.5 GHz.

```
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor 
performance
performance
performance
performance
performance
performance
performance
performance
```

When idle the system looks as expected:

```
  $ sudo i7z
  Real Current Frequency 3367.10 MHz [99.94 x 33.69] (Max of below)
  Core [core-id]  :Actual Freq (Mult.)      C0%   Halt(C1)%  C3 %   C6 %   C7 %  Temp      VCore
    Core 1 [0]:       3367.10 (33.69x)      3.04    11.7       1    14.5    67.1    48      1.1041
    Core 2 [1]:       3005.90 (30.08x)      2.49    7.09       1    4.53    83.2    47      1.1041
    Core 3 [2]:       3109.65 (31.11x)         1    3.15       1       1    93.3    49      1.1042
    Core 4 [3]:       3280.22 (32.82x)      4.97    6.89       1    4.18    78.9    48      1.1040
```

However, performing a simple `systemctl start docker` — that is *not even* running any docker container — has the immediate effect of underclocking the CPU around 700-900 MHz and induces a 100% CPU usage on all cores.

```
$ sudo systemctl start docker && i7z
Max Frequency without considering Turbo 1898.94 MHz (99.94 x [19])
Max TURBO Multiplier (if Enabled) with 1/2/3/4 Cores is  39x/38x/37x/37x
Real Current Frequency 945.70 MHz [99.94 x 9.46] (Max of below)
        Core [core-id]  :Actual Freq (Mult.)      C0%   Halt(C1)%  C3 %   C6 %   C7 %  Temp      VCore
        Core 1 [0]:       945.63 (9.46x)        99.9    47.5       0       0       0    52      0.6639
        Core 2 [1]:       945.65 (9.46x)        99.9    47.5       0       0       0    51      0.6642
        Core 3 [2]:       945.68 (9.46x)        99.9    47.5       0       0       0    53      0.6641
        Core 4 [3]:       945.70 (9.46x)        99.9    47.5       0       0       0    51      0.6641
```

Stopping the service immediately puts the CPU back to a normal state.

Additional frequency info:

```
  $ cpupower frequency-info
  analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
  hardware limits: 400 MHz - 3.90 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 2.50 GHz and 3.90 GHz.
                  The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
  current CPU frequency: 3.23 GHz (asserted by call to kernel)
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
```

Turbo mode is enabled:

```
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo 
0
```

I even tried to ignore the BIOS frequency limitations by setting the value in `/sys/module/processor/parameters/ignore_ppc` to `1`.

I tried performing these tests under Ubuntu and got the exact same results, which leads me to think the issue is not OS specific. I was using a Docker version a few months old and upgrading (to `18.09.8-ce, build 0dd43dd87f`) didn't help. I can run all my other usual working stuff without capping the CPU usage, including multiple instances of my heavy IDE and Chrome with dozens of tabs open.

At this point I'm running out of ideas and I'd love to hear any suggestions! Thanks a lot.